# Sublime 2 text - build during saving a .js file

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

Please, is there an option, how to disable auto-build, when i am trying to save a .js file?

I was elaborating a node.js + express tutorial, and all the time I've saved the file, the build was starting the node.exe binary, what is something that i dont want, only solution was to tick the Build system for example for JSLint, but it still tries to build when I'm saving a file.

I know there is an tick option in Tools -> Save all on Build, but i cant find the inverse option - disable Build all on save.

I've installed the Node package for Sublime 2, and even when its disabled the build system Nodejs trys to build during the saving proces (ctrl+s)

thanks for all hints!

Here are my custom user packages:

"installed_packages":
    [
        "Dart",
        "JavaScript Console",
        "JavaScript Snippets",
        "JSLint",
        "Mocha Runner",
        "Mocha Snippets",
        "Nodejs",
        "Package Control",
        "Require Node.js Modules Helper",
        "sublime-jslint"
    ],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was caused by the nodejs package for sublime text 2 - after removing the package completly (not just disabling) I got an error msg when trying to save the app.js

> pressed CTRL+S error: Error trying to parse build system: No data in
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text
>   2\Packages\Nodejs\Nodejs.sublime-build:1:1

Problem solved, but I still don't know, why sublime was calling nodejs.sublime-build direct after saving the app.js file.

Strange behavior, maybe a bug or a unwanted feature (When a file is saved, the pre-set build system is called direct after the save)

Problem solved by removing the whole package.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the `Tools` menu, does the `Build` option have the shortcut `Ctrl-S` next to it? If so, your key-mapping probably got messed up at some point. Put the following line in your `Key Bindings - User` file (in the `Preferences` menu) and save it by selecting `File -> Save` (double check that its shortcut is still `Ctrl-S` as well).

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "build" },
```

Remove the `,` at the end if it's the last (or only) line in your user keymap.

You can go to `Preferences -> Package Settings` and through the menu options for each entry, looking for additional keymap definitions. Also, check `Preferences -> Key Bindings (Default)` and search for `build` to see if it got changed there to `ctrl+s`. If so, feel free to change it back to `b`.

Comment: Thx for the quick anwser, but in Sublime2 i have everything sofar ok with key bindings (default, user is empty) { "keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "save" }.

Comment: I just dont know why sublime tries to build when I'm saving the file.

here is the code http://pastebin.com/dpDeHCZ7

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified "save" is actually being run on `ctrl+s`? If not, open up the console `ctrl+backtick` and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` Then press `ctrl+s` If save is being run, you should see `command: save`. If not, one of the plugins is grabbing the `ctrl+s` keybinding before it falls back to default.

If save is running, on of the plugins probably has an `on_post_save` or `on_pre_save` listener that is kicking off the build. I checked what I thought would be most likely (Mocha Runner) and it does have an `on_post_save` listener. I don't know if that's what you are seeing, but it would certainly explain it. Try disabling the plugins and rerunning the save to see if that is the case. If it is, you may want to create an issue on whatever plugin, asking them to make the "build on save" optional.

Comment: I got this

sublime.log_commands(True)

command: save

Writing file /C/Users/username/NodeSandbox/webproject/app.js with encoding UTF-8

Running taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node 

C:\Users\username\NodeSandbox\webproject\app.js

command: show_panel {"panel": "console", "toggle": true}

Comment: Have you tried disabling plugins to see if one of them is doing the build on save?

Comment: "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Mocha Runner",
  "Vintage",
  "Require Node.js Modules Helper",
  "Nodejs",
  "Dart",
  "sublime-jslint"
 ]

strange is when i disable to nodejs package, problem still remains.

Comment: Important note - when I open the same file in another text editor (notepad.exe) and I change it and save again, the build process doesn't happen then. With notepad++ as well - on save, no build and node.exe not started. so this issue is bound with sublime 2