# nodejs package for sublime-text 3 autobuilds on save for some reason

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3

Essentially, I'm having the same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751691/sublime-2-text-build-during-saving-a-js-file) - immediately after installing the nodejs package for sublime, it started auto-building my js files every time I hit `Ctrl+S`, which is insane. The solution in that link is, sadly, to entirely remove that package, something I'm not inclined to do if possible.

But not only does it try to build every time, it also fails (somehow), I get this:

```
node: no process found
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Which is weird considering I have node installed normally (running `node filename.js` in terminal works fine). And yes, before you ask, `Ctrl+B` is still the shortcut for building, and I couldn't find anything in the preferences that explains this odd behavior.

Furthermore, If I open up the console with Ctrl+` I see one repeated message over and over again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py", line 445, in is_enabled_
    raise ValueError("is_enabled must return a bool", self)
ValueError: ('is_enabled must return a bool', <Nodejs.Nodejs.NodeUglifyCommand object at 0x7f62939e1350>)
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

p.s. I'm running Sublime Text 3 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit).